# Why does .Net Framework 4 Extended take so long to boot?

Tags: .net-framework, .net-4.0

I just installed [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) and found that "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended" is taking 177 seconds to boot. Why does it take so long, and is there any way of speeding this up?

Comment: Was this the first reboot? If so, it was probably NGEN'ng the assemblies still.

Comment: The .NET Framework 4 is just a framework, it doesn't really do anything to "boot" (unless it was the reboot after installation as @leppie suggested). Are you sure this application isn't mistaking it for something built using the Framework?

Comment: @vcsjones: well the OP states he installed some app called Soluto.

Comment: @leppie: Soluto is a boot benchmarking tool and I am just wondering if it is getting confused about something.

Comment: Not the first reboot, and yes it's entirely possible that Soluto's reporting incorrectly. I was just wondering if anyone else was seeing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that .NET Framework 4 Extended includes an app called PresentationFontCache.exe. This was causing the slow boot and also using a lot of my CPU. I found a fix [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/presentationfontcacheexe-uses-50-of-my-cpu/4200fe85-458f-4f19-b791-1fe5395304da) - just delete the Font*.dat files from C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local.